# Добавить элементы в HashMap

Tags: java, java-hashmap

Хочу добавить несколько элементов. Как лучше всего это реализовать?

```
public class Firm  
{  
    private HashMap<Integer, Worker> hm = new HashMap<>();  
    private void addOfficWorker(String name)  
    {  
        ...  hm.put(key, new officeWorker(name);
    }  
}
```

Это можно сделать с помощью итератора?

Comment: Может вам не нужно Map стурктура? достаточно List/Set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается через цикл. Например, так (в качестве ключа (key) каждой записи в HashMap использован счетчик i). Будет добавлено 10 работников (officeWorker):

```
private void addOfficWorker(String name)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    hm.put(i, new officeWorker(name));
}
```